# Is there a regex pattern for custom page range validation in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, frontend

I need a regex for page sequences that

***matches***:

- 1
- 1, 4-5
- 1, 4-5, 8, 11, 13-14

***but doesn't match***:

- 1,,,,
- 1, 4-5-
- 1, 4--------2233-----,,,,

I have tried the following patterns but they don't work:

```
/^(\d*-\d*,?|\d*,?)*$/
/^(\d*-{1}\d*,?|\d*,?)*$/
```

I also want to validate user input while the user types, so the pattern needs to allow tailing `-` and `,` in certain cases. The example React code for allowing input with a particular pattern looks like this:

```
const customPageInputChange = (e) => {
  if(e.target.value.match(/.../) !== null) {
    setCustomPage(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/4zqwq1fj/ for a full example with input validation.

Comment: Did you try https://regex101.com/ or a similar explanation and evaluation service for help with creating your regex?

Comment: No- @FelixSchütz. Can you help here

Answer (score 2):

One possible regex:

```regex
^(\d+(-\d+)?, )*\d+(-\d+)?$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/txVh3e/1 for test cases.

If you also want to check whether the pages are increasing, a regex is not really suitable, and you should opt for checking the strings programmatically.

If you want to validate user input while the user is typing, you need a regex allowing trailing `-` and `,`. One possible regex:

```regex
^(\d+(-\d+)?, ?)*(\d+-?\d*)?$
```

See https://regex101.com/r/rKx6lq/1 for test cases and https://jsfiddle.net/qtb4yd7s/ for a demo.

Comment: The above thing works in the regex101 but not in javascript @Felix. Can you provide a solution that works in js and react

Comment: I dont want to check page increasing if this pattern is matched it should allow typing in input field

Comment: See my edit, I added a JavaScript code sample.

Comment: Try here in the pattern and check https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/4zqwq1fj/

Comment: What should I check? If you want to check the input while the user types, you obviously need a different regex, which allows trailing `,` and `-`.

Comment: I need a regex check the input while the user types exactly

Comment: Please clarify your question accordingly.

Comment: See my edit, I added another regex for validating user input while the user types.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that solved my problem. @Felix

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

In Javascript you can use [regex.test(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to return a boolean to see if the pattern matched.

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:-\d+)?` Optionally match - and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `,\s*` Match a comma and optional whitespace chars
  - `\d+(?:-\d+)?` The same as previous pattern
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to als match a single occurrence
- `$` End of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN17NQ/1)

Comment: The above pattern does allow ,(comma) after a number

Comment: @nitinpremanand No, it does not.

Comment: Try here in the pattern and check https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/4zqwq1fj/

Comment: @nitinpremanand It does not allow only a training comma https://regex101.com/r/ypN1xP/1

Comment: @nitinpremanand Use with test `if(/^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\s*\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$/.test(e.target.value)) {}`

Comment: @Thefourthbird if you test it in jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/4zqwq1fj it is not working

Comment: @nitinpremanad The pattern works for the whole string. If you want to validate while typing you need to allow the characters while typing and validate the whole pattern when submitting.